# Why does App stop running when it becomes background in iPhone in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, background

When it becomes background, the App stop running in iPhone in Xcode.

I don't know why it finishes running and It haven't done like this ever since.

I don't want it to finish running when iPhone is connected with Xcode.

Comment: What do you mean with "*finish*"? Does it terminate? Does it crash? Is it still visible in the task overview when you double-press the home button?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I mean it terminate.When I double-press the home button and come back the app, it doesn't finish running.But when I press the home button once, the app finish running and Xcode shows the message "Finished running ◯◯ (App name) on my iPhone.

Comment: You can check the option in Xcode Targets>Capabilities.
http://imgur.com/3wBw7WU

Comment: Other my apps don't stop running when it become background and in Targets>Capabilities, there is no check in "Background Mode".it is same to now app...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple restricts background execution to save battery and for good performance of running app.

Your app can't run in background by default. You are allowed background execution for some kind of tasks like location updates, music, finite length tasks, voice over ip etc. But you have to register for background execution by change app build settings : under targets - capabilities - background modes

you should refer [Apple documentation for background execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

Hope this will help :)